# SQL Server 2008 Repopulate Index "Update" Option

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-indexing

I have created a single catalog named EntryCatalog. I assigned a table named Entry to the catalog and selected Notes and Title columns (both nvarchar max) with Track Changes set to Automatic.

I did not put anything in the Population Schedule options thinking there has to be some way to have it populate automatically and kind of "manage itself."  So in the FTI properties for the Entry table there is an Actions checkbox. I checked that and selected the UPDATE radio button (rather than Incremental or Full) because the docs say "The full-text index is updated whenever the data in the base table is modified." I think that's what I want...does this apply to when inserts are made to the Entry table?

Maybe I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how FTI works. I'm hoping I can just set up a catalog to index the 2 columns in this table and when new records are inserted they are indexed as well automatically. Can this be done, or do you HAVE TO have some kind of scheduling option set up? Is that what repopulating really is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, To implement full-text indexing in SQL Server, you should take the following steps:

1. Create a full-text catalog, if required.
2. Create the full-text index.
3. Modify the list of noise words (SQL Server 2005) or stop words (SQL Server 2008), if necessary.
4. If required, Modify the thesaurus for the language being used.

> "The full-text index is updated whenever the data in the base table is
>   modified." I think that's what I want...does this apply to when
>   inserts are made to the Entry table?

Answer: YES

> I'm hoping I can just set up a catalog to index the 2 columns in this
>   table and when new records are inserted they are indexed as well
>   automatically. Can this be done, or do you HAVE TO have some kind of
>   scheduling option set up? Is that what repopulating really is?

If I'm not wrong you don't have to any such thing. Things will be managed by SQL Server 2008 automatically. First you need to create Full-Text Catalog and after you create your full-text catalog, you’re ready to create your full-text index. You can then associate the index with the new catalog. Then modify stop words. You are done.

The following link will help you to understand the basic of "Full-Text Indexing in SQL Server".

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I originally wrote this question based on not understanding what the answer is for what the "update" option is vs full or incremental. I get what full and incremental do. What I didn't get was what the Update radio button option does in 2008. Answer is here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879321.aspx